# Floating Inductor Simulation Using Only BJTs?

Tags: bjt, inductor, gyrator

I know it is possible to replace large-ish floating inductors (~ 5mH) with
a gyrator, typically using two opamps:

[image: Gyrator]

What I've unsuccessfully tried to solve is : can we build something equivalent
to the circuit above, but using only caps, resistors and BJT's ?

I guess it is theoretically possible, given that an OpAmp can in practice
be built out of caps, resistors and BJT's, but I guess the question becomes:
is there a *simple* circuit, made only of BJTs caps and resistors that
can properly simulate a *floating* 5mH inductor ?

Comment: In what way do you mean "floating" - the picture you show is a grounded impedance and not floating.

Comment: You do know op-amps are made of transistors, right?

Comment: @ConnorWolf : you read the last three lines of my question, right ?

Comment: @Andyaka : yes, the picture I am showing is grounded, but IIUC this specific gyrator implementation will actually work even when not grounded, as opposed to other gyrator types that can only replace a grounded inductor.

Comment: Where will Vout be?

Comment: @andyaka : where the ground is I guess.

Comment: I did. Did you mean to ask "How can I build a simple op-amp out of discrete devices?" Because if that's what you're underlying question is, you need to change the title.

Comment: @blondiepassesby - I don't think it will be - the op-amps make the input node look like an inductor relative to the bottom of Z5 (ground on your circuit) but that doesn't mean you can expect the bottom of Z5 to look like the same inductor.

Comment: @ConnorWolf : It looks like you managed to somehow miss the word "simple", but hey, since spelling things out seems to be required, let's have a stab at it. An OpAmp is a generic device that can be used for many different things. The internal circuit is therefore complex. In this specific circuit the two OpAmps are used for exactly one thing, simulating an inductor. The hope here is to find a BJT based circuit that is much *simpler* than two full generic OpAmp when implementing that particular use of two OpAmps. Is the question clear enough now ?

Comment: @ConnorWolf Another way to phrase the question would be: when very simple amplification of a signal over a narrow set of constraints is needed, sure you can use a full OpAmp, but sometimes, a single BJT does the job. In the circuit above, do we really need two full opamps, or is there a *simpler*, BJT-based circuit that can more or less perform the same function.

Comment: @Andyaka : you're saying the circuit isn't symmetrical. I see. Thanks, this is very useful.

Comment: It's hard to analyse but from what I know there is no reason to believe it can be used as a floating inductor. Maybe someone knows differently.

Comment: Ha. This looks like it's out of my old prof Sedra's book. There's a modification of this with an additional op-amp voltage follower and a OTA that properly simulates a floating inductor. See, for example, "NEW SINGLE-CAPACITOR SIMULATIONS OF FLOATING INDUCTORS" by Senai.

Comment: If you can find a BJT with the right shape you can wrap a bunch of turns around it....  @SpehroPefhany Interesting paper by Senai, thanks for the pointer.  Someday it may come in handy to know something like that is possible.

Comment: @john D :funny, but not entirely sure it's useful.

Comment: @blondiepassesby are you still interested in this problem? I may have some answers. The GIC circuit is difficult to use as a starting point for conversion to BJTs because it is so hard to follow.